# Getting diffs for file changes detected by rpm -V

Tags: rpm

I have an installation that has been tampered with, and I want to find out what exactly has been changed.

I can run

```
rpm -V MY_PACKAGES
```

which gives me a list of modified files. Now I am looking for a convenient way to see the diffs (assuming that all files have textual content) against the original rpms (which I have available).

What would be the easiest way of doing this, given that I am dealing with ~20 packages and ~200 changed files. Is there something like "rpm diff"???

Answer (score 13):

```
#
# Install yumdownloader 
#
yum install yum-utils

#
# search modified files (in this case: from pam_ldap)
#
rpm -V pam_ldap
S.5....T.  c /etc/pam_ldap.conf

#
# make tmp-dir and download rpm
#
mkdir Temp
cd Temp
yumdownloader pam_ldap

#
# extract rpm to current folder
#
rpm2cpio pam_ldap-185-11.el6.x86_64.rpm  | cpio -idmv

#
# check diff
#
diff etc/pam_ldap.conf /etc/pam_ldap.conf


rpm -V explained: 

    c %config configuration file.
    d %doc documentation file.
    g %ghost file (i.e. the file contents are not
    included in the package payload).
    l %license license file.
    r %readme readme file.

    S file Size differs
    M Mode differs (includes permissions and file type)
    5 MD5 sum differs
    D Device major/minor number mismatch
    L readLink(2) path mismatch
    U User ownership differs
    G Group ownership differs
    T mTime differs
```